# Laravel website permanent https redirection and remove 'public' from url with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, https, laravel-5

I have removed public word from url by applying following code in .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

It is working undoubtedly. But also trying to set permanent redirection http to https. Using following code in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Please tell me where is the issue? It should remove public folder from url as well as permanent redirection to https URL

Comment: Why not just point the domain to the /public folder?

Comment: You need to move the rule that forces HTTPs above your normal rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) applies only to the *next* `RewriteRule`

> The RewriteCond directive defines a rule condition. One or more RewriteCond can precede a RewriteRule directive. The **following rule** is then only used if both the current state of the URI matches its pattern, and if these conditions are met.

So in your case, you must move `RewriteCond` in front of the second `RewriteRule`

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Although, since you want to enforce HTTPS, you should move that to the front, e.g.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

When everything works as it should, you may replace `R` with `R=301`. Never test with [`R=301`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542).